# Email not getting sent by the form

Tags: html

When I click on the submit button of the following form, it does not send an email to the mentioned email. Please guide me why it is not working.

Thanks.

```
<form action="mailto:fahad@inspurate.com"  role="form" id="submit-mobile-box" style="color:#FFF;">
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <input style=" float: left; margin-right: 4%;" type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" placeholder="Enter full name" >
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <input style=" float: left;" type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="Enter Surname">
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <input style="width: 50%; float: left;" type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileNumber" placeholder="Enter Mobile number">
    </span>

    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <input style="width: 50%; float: left;" type="text" class="form-control" id="landLineNumber" placeholder="Enter Landline number">
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <input style="float: left;" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <textarea style="float: left;" rows="5" class="form-control" id="pickup" placeholder="Enter Pick up Address"></textarea>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <input style="width: 50%; float: left;" type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileMake" placeholder="Enter Mobile Device Make">
    </span>

    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <input style="width: 50%; float: left;" type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileModel" placeholder="Enter Mobile Device Model">
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
        <label style="color:#666666;"> Warranty </label>
        <input style="color:#666666 !important;" type="radio" name="warranty" value="true"><span style="color:#666666">Yes</span></input>
        <input style="color:#666666 !important;" type="radio" name="warranty" value="false"><span style="color:#666666">No</span></input>

    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
        <label style="color:#666666;"> Are you looking to buy new phone ? </label>
        <input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="newPhone" value="true"><span style="color:#666666">Yes</span></input>
        <input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="newPhone" value="false"><span style="color:#666666">No</span></input>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
        <label style="color:#666666;"> If Yes, then when ? </label>
        <input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="when" value="1"><span style="color:#666666">1 month</span></input>
        <input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="when" value="6"><span style="color:#666666">6 month</span></input>
        <input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="when" value="1"><span style="color:#666666">12 month</span></input>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
      <label style="color:#666666;"> Desbcribe the issue your are having with your mobile phone;</label>
      <textarea style="width: 100%; float: left;" rows="5" class="form-control" id="mobileIssue" placeholder="Enter Mobile Issue Model"></textarea>
    </span>  
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitMobile();">
      <strong style="color:#666666;">
        Submit
      </strong>
    </button>
    <p style="float:right;">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Because HTML pages don't send mails, that's what you need serverside code for. This will however open up the visitor's mail clients with a new mail containing the specified subject, addressee and a list of form fields and their values.

Comment: `<Form action="mailto:fahad@inspurate.com" ` it never work ..do you know form posting ??

Comment: @AnantDabhi: Please don't stereotype.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't send email because mailto: protocol only opens the email client of the user that send the form. You need a server-side process to send email, like PHP something like this:

```
 $from = "your@email.com";
 $to = "destination@email.com";
 $subject ="This is an email";
 $message = "This is the body of the message";
 mail($to, $subject, $message);
```